# Laravel Postgre invalid text representation

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel-5

I got an error from my Laravel App

> Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "2" (SQL: select * from "tasks" where extract(day from "due_date") = 20 and "status" != 2)

my Query on Laravel Controller is as follows:

`$datav['dueTasks'] = Task::whereDay('due_date', date('d'))->where('status','!=','2')->get();`

this is a migrate from mysql db, so The problem might be with the status not equal 2 syntax.

anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the migration table.

My "tasks"."status" is a boolean datatype, which in mysql turns into TINYINT.

In postgre I changed the datatype to smallInt and it runs.

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->date('start_date');
      $table->date('due_date');
      $table->**smallInteger**('status')->default(1);
      $table->smallInteger('priority')->default(8);
      $table->text('description');
      $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```